# Subset a region from boundary coordinates using imrect - Matlab

Tags: matlab

Based on the question in [Subset a region from boundary coordinates - Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744474/subset-a-region-from-boundary-coordinates-matlab) I tried to use imrect instead (although it is limiting to rectangles without an angle it).

Nevertheless, I have problem with the output as I do not get any x,y coordinates. Why?

Script:

```
clc;
clear; 

I = imread('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/Astroid_created_with_Elipses_with_a_plus_b_const.svg/330px-Astroid_created_with_Elipses_with_a_plus_b_const.svg.png'); 
I = rgb2gray(I);
I = imcomplement(I);
level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);

BW_filled = imfill(BW,'holes');

boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_filled);  
figure,imshow(I) ;

hold on;

b = boundaries{1}; 
plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'b','LineWidth',2);

xq = b(:,2);
yq = b(:,1);
h = imrect;

pos = getPosition(h);

X1 = round(pos(1));
Y1 = round(pos(2));
X2 = round(X1 + pos(3));
Y2 = round(Y1 + pos(4));

xv=[X1 X2];
yv=[Y1 Y2];

scatter(X1,Y1 ,'r' )  
scatter(X2,Y2 ,'r' )  

[in,on] = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv, yv) %xq and yq are inside or on the edge of the polygon area defined by xv and yv
```

Comment: Do you mean that pos is empty? Anyway, you might want to put a `pause()` before `pos = getPosition(h);' to let the user adjust the rectangle. Otherwise you'll read its position as soon as it is placed.

Comment: The [in,on] only shows 0 and 1 but not coordinates.

Comment: The `inpolygon` function does not retun coordinates. It _returns in indicating if the query points specified by xq and yq are inside or on the edge of the polygon area defined by xv and yv._ It also _returns on indicating if the query points are on the edge of the polygon area_

Comment: OK, so is there a way to get the coordinates?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The boundary coordinates(marked by blue line) inside the imrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inpoligon` returns a list of boolean values to indicate if the points xq and yq are inside the polygon. To obtain the coordinates of the corresponding points, you can use logical indexing; just add this at the end of your code:

```
x_in = xq(in | on);
y_in = yq(in | on);
scatter(x_in,y_in ,'g.' )
```